# Validation for float number in php

Tags: php, validation, text, field

How can I validate to enter only float numbers from `1.0 -5.0`? My system right now can accept:

- negative float
- negative integers
- symbols like `+`, it is not displayed in the database
- letters like `a`, it is not displayed in the database.

Below I have some code for checking to enter float number.

savelibscores.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$value1=$_POST['s3'];
$value2=$_POST['s4'];
$value3=$_POST['year'];


if((filter_var($value1,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)&& $value1>0) && (filter_var($value2,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) && $value2>0)) {
echo 'TRUE.';

} else {
    echo 'FALSE.';
}

if(!empty($value1) && !empty($value2) && !empty($value3)){
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `library`(s3,s4,year) VALUES ('".$value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."')")or die(mysql_error());
}
else{
    echo "Please fill all the fields. Please be sure to use float values also.";
}

}
```

Comment: Something like [is_float()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I pulled this from PHP's website `http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php` and `http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $value1=$_POST['s3'];
  $value2=$_POST['s4'];
  $value3=$_POST['year'];
  $options = array(
    'options' => array(
                      'min_range' => -5,
                      'max_range' => 1,
                      )
   if(!empty($value1) && !empty($value2) && !empty($value3)){

    if((filter_var($value1,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT,$options) && (filter_var($value2,FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT,$options))) 
      {
        echo 'TRUE.';
        $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `library`(s3,s4,year) VALUES ('".$value1."','".$value2."','".$value3."')")or die(mysql_error());
      } else {
        echo 'Please be sure to use float values.';
      } 

} else {
    echo "Please fill all the fields. Please be sure to use float values also.";
}
}
```

Comment: In order my user to enter `3.1 `, I have to open the code and to change for example `$int_a = '1';` into `$int_a = '3.1';` . It is not helpful

Comment: Hmm. OK. Since you asked. I also reformated the ifs to be clearer. Why check for empty variables after validating them.

Comment: @ joegyoung Thank you so much !!! I am so happy, it doesn't accept the `+` symbol. But it accepts `-3.1`. How can I stop it?

Comment: I didn't paste the whole answer. Now it does. I forgot the $_POST array